# To use another table with joins or something else

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've want to implement `Title` with selectable values such as `Mr`, `Mrs`, `Ms`, `Miss` etc

Is it the best practice to implement another table with `titles` with `user_id` and `join` them together with `users` table or have `enumerable` in the column?

I'm hearing that `joins` can be a performance issue later when the app scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need another table to reference the title of a person.  Just create a `Title` field in the table.  Then control the list of Titles a user can select via a drop down list populated by your code.

If a person can have more than one `Title` then you are going to have to have a secondary table.  Probably something like the below structure.  Then use join to retrieve them all.

```
Person
id  
firstname
lastname

PersonTitle
Personid
Title
```

Comment: Or another solution you can add new field called `title_id:integer` and set the alias (`Mr.`, `Ms.`, etc) on your model. For example `0` for `Mr.`, `1` for `Ms.`, etc. This way was more flexible on my opinion, in the future you need too add more alias you can add to your model and `select` form, without interfere any table. You can also change `Mr.` to `Sir` for example anytime. Just sayin